# With Java 8's Stream API, how can I write a filter function that is pure?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

If I'm writing a filter function, I'm depending on an outside variable for my filter. For example:

```
public List<String> getMatches(String search) {
    return stringList.stream().filter(str -> str.contains(search)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This filter depends on an outside parameter. I'm just wondering how to write a filter using a pure function if you don't know the criteria beforehand.

Comment: would you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: do you mean: "stringList.stream().filter(search ,(str, search) -> str.contains(search)).collect(Collectors.toList());" ? if yes, I developed my own stream libraby AbacusUtil which can help you to that: "Stream.of(stringList).filter(search, (str, search) -> str.contains(search)).toList();"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This lambda:

```
    str -> str.contains(search)
```

**is** a pure function.

A function is not pure if it performs side effects.  This one doesn't.

---

Then there is the issue of whether a function depends on something ... and what that means.

But consider what actually happens in this example:

- The `search` object is a `String` and therefore immutable.  So you can't "break" the filter by mutating the `String`.
- If you were able to change the value of the `stream` variable after the lambda captured its value, you would get a compilation error.

So, the "dependency" does no harm.

(It might be harmful if `search` was a `stringBuilder`, and something else mutated it.  Or if the lambda itself did the mutating.  But those are different examples.)

Comment: Perhaps the OP is trying to write a method reference, but that would require an API change. +1

Answer (score 2):

The fact that a function relies on data from outside itself doesn't alone make it impure.

`search` is a String, which is immutable. That means it can't be modified after it's created, so you dont have to worry about it being a "vector" for side effects.

It also wouldn't be possible to create a version of `filter` that is strictly "pure". `filter` has no way of knowing whether  data its filtering function uses is immutable or not.